# How do i use moped on ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I downloaded ROS Grrovy prebuilt with ubuntu. I checked  the moped documentation.. it says that ROS already has moped installed on it.  I used the 'make' command in the src folder ,but still it said makefile not found.

If someone has run moped on ROS .. can you please guide me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59969/how-do-i-use-moped-on-ros/) by [Shogun](https://answers.ros.org/users/4608/shogun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check the basic tutorials for ROS : the Makefile is not in the src directory but at the node root.

---

Originally posted by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) with karma: 697 on 2013-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1